# Is there any investment model with time-varying depreciation rate?

Tags: investment, discount-rate

Is there investment model with different depreciation rate.

For example, d1(depreciation rate in 1 period), d2(depreciation rate in 2 period)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A type of model you might be interested on is one where **the depreciation rate is endogenous**. This means, it depends on the value of other variables in the model, instead of being exogenous and constant (naturally, you can have a variable depreciation rate but exogenous, but that is as *ad-hoc* as a constant depreciation rate).

One example is [this model](http://www.nber.org/papers/w2571.pdf). Equation 19.4 shows the formula of the depreciaton rate (which the authors also coll net utilization rate). Then, they state:

> Thus the adjustment path for the capital utilization rate is a flexible accelerator.
>   This result rigorously establishes the empirical finding obtained by Nadiri and Rosen (1969) that the adjustment' path of the
>   capital utilization rate is similar to the paths of capital and labor growth rates which are governed by flexible accelerators. Along the
>   dynamic path, **as the capital intensity decreases the net utilization rate declines for two reasons.** First, there is the direct effect of the
>   capital intensity on the net utilization rate. A decrease in the capital intensity leads the firm to reallocate resources towards capital output
>   which decreases the rate. Second, there is the indirect effect, which arises because the decrease in capital intensity causes the price of
>   unutilized capital to increase. Since the marginal value of unutilized capital increases, the firm then utilizes less of its capital and so the
>   utilization rate falls. Thus $k^° > k^*$ implies that $\delta^° > \delta^*$. These results mean that along the dynamic path the net capital utilization rate
>   and the rate of capital investment are inversely related while the net capital utilization rate and the labor investment rate are directly
>   correlated.

[This paper](http://econpapers.repec.org/article/oupoxecpp/v_3a61_3ay_3a2009_3ai_3a3_3ap_3a440-466.htm) presents another model. They show that "embodied" technical change (i.e. technical change which comes with **new** machines rather than occur amid current machines) decreases the lifetime of capital, thereby increasing the depreciation rate.

[This paper](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/003465300556832) finds empirical support for a variable depreciation rate.